# Plotting Bar and Line charts with Pandas data frame using secondary Y axis and adding the legend together

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I created a plot in which I have a bar chart on primary Y axis and a line chart on a secondary Y axis using the Pandas dataframe.The X axis is common so used twinx method.

This is the code I used

```
ax = df.plot(x=['TIME'],y =['Column A'],kind='bar',use_index=True,color='g',legend=True)
ax.set_ylabel("Label A")

ax2 = ax.twinx()

ax2.plot(df[['Column B']].values,linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=2.0,color ='b')
ax2.set_ylabel("Label B")
```

This creates the desired chart but shows only the primary legend. I tried changing the ax2.plot lines as

```
ax2.plot(df[['Column B']].values,linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=2.0,color ='b',legend=True)
```

But this gives me an error as "TypeError: There is no line property "legend"" could you guys please look into it as how to show the combined legends belonging to both the attributes.

Many Thanks.
MO Chen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do use the `legend` method to handle the legends for each axis, e.g.

```
ax.legend('A', loc=1)

# ....

ax2.legend('B', loc=2)
```

Here's a guide to legends in `matplotlib`: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html

Comment: Joe thanks for the reply, it works but then I have to pass the legends manually , can I make it automatic getting the names same as the labels..??

Comment: Not through the `matplotlib` API but you've already entered the column name manually so I don't see the problem, just define the column you're plotting as a variable and then pass it to both, e.g. `col = 'Column B'; ax.plot(df[col].values, ...); ax.legend(col, ...)`

Comment: Hello, When I save the plot the legends become stacked on one another though I chose different loc for them. However MATPLOTLIB plot shows the correct locations.

Comment: How are you saving them? Maybe you should ask a new question as this is  off topic.